# How to trigger google drive web app url using powershell?

Tags: powershell, google-apps-script

I published a web app url which i want to trigger using powershell. i can do it opening firefox using powershell command

`[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("firefox","https://script.google.com/URL")`

but this is not a good idea, what if any reason i logged out from google. is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

i used `Invoke-WebRequest` to browse the url and set anonymous can execute it